# Bash: cp doesn't copy from tmpfs to hard drive

Tags: bash, scripts

I was making bash script for game server, however the script doesn't work as I expect it to.

The idea of script is to make folder `/ramdisk` then mount it as `tmpfs`. Then copy files from `/server/` that will be needed in `/ramdisk`, backup game's worlds (that are store now in `/ramdisk`), start server (which again is in `/ramdisk`), when server shuts down copy files out of `/ramdisk` back to `/server` and then unmount ramdisk.

However the files aren't copied from `/ramdisk` as expected... I believe that they don't copy at all, as all changes made in `/ramdisk` aren't saved back to `/server` directory, after the script finishes.

Also the script is saying that copying was successful and `cp` does not give any error code.

Here is the script I am using:

```
echo Mounting RAMDISK...

if [ ! -d "/ramdisk" ]; then
    echo Creating folder /ramdisk
    mkdir /ramdisk
fi
mount -t tmpfs -o size=512M tmpfs /ramdisk
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo -e "Mounting RAMDISK... \033[0;32mFinished\033[1;37m"
else
    echo -e "Mounting RAMDISK... \033[0;31mFAILED!!!\033[1;37m"
    echo -e "\033[0;31mCritical Error\033[1;37m"
    exit
fi

echo Copying files to RAMDISK...

cp -ar /server/* /ramdisk
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo -e "Copying files to RAMDISK... \033[0;32mFinished\033[1;37m"
else
    echo -e "Copying files to RAMDISK... \033[0;31mFAILED!!!\033[1;37m"
    echo -e "\033[0;31mCritical Error\033[1;37m"
    exit
fi
tm=$(date "+%d-%m-%y_%H-%M-%S")
mkdir /server-backups/$tm-backup

echo Backing up World...
mkdir /server-backups/$tm-backup/world
cp -ar /ramdisk/world/* /server-backups/$tm-backup/world
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo -e "Backing up World... \033[0;32mFinished\033[1;37m"
else
    echo -e "Backing up World... \033[0;31mFAILED!!!\033[1;37m"
fi
echo Backing up Nether...
mkdir /server-backups/$tm-backup/world_nether
cp -ar /ramdisk/world_nether/* /server-backups/$tm-backup/world_nether
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo -e "Backing up Nether... \033[0;32mFinished\033[1;37m"
else
    echo -e "Backing up Nether... \033[0s;31mFAILED!!!\033[1;37m"
fi
echo Backing up End...
mkdir /server-backups/$tm-backup/world_the_end
cp -ar /ramdisk/world_the_end/* /server-backups/$tm-backup/world_the_end
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo -e "Backing up End... \033[0;32mFinished\033[1;37m"
else
    echo -e "Backing up End... \033[0;31mFAILED!!!\033[1;37m"
fi

java -Xms2G -Xmx2G -jar /ramdisk/bukkit.jar -o false


#The error appears to be here

echo Copying files out of RAMDISK...
cp -ar /ramdisk/* /server
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo -e "Copying files out of RAMDISK... \033[0;32mFinished\033[1;37m"
else
    echo -e "Copying files out of RAMDISK... \033[0;31mFAILED!!!\033[1;37m"
    echo -e "\033[0;31mCritical Error\033[1;37m"
    exit
fi

#End of error block

echo Unmounting RAMDISK...
umount /ramdisk
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo -e "Unmounting RAMDISK... \033[0;32mFinished\033[1;37m"
else
    echo -e "Unmounting RAMDISK... \033[0;31mFAILED!!!\033[1;37m"
fi
```

This script was written by myself, and I admit that I haven't made much bash scripts in my life. I will be very happy if someone would be able to help me with this.

Comment: What error message ? my guess is you need to use the full path to java. IMO best to use the full path to commands in scripts. If you use the command multiple times, set it as a variable .

Comment: Thing is that I see no error in script execution, everything apparently goes fine. Also If I run the script without copying to `/ramdisk` and execute everything from hard drive, everything goes fine. I want however to use ramdisk as my hard drive is very slow and it has impact on game server